# Remove freehub on this bike

Tags: cassette, freehub

I am struggling to remove a freehub from my bike. Please help me to disassemble the hub as it is stuck. When I stop pedaling the cassette keeps turning, to the point where it pulls the chain and derailleur.
I think the freehub is full of grease and gunk which doesnt allow my back wheel to ratchet when I stop pedalling.

This is how the wheel looks after a bit of disassembling already.
[image]

And this other side
[image]

I dont know how to disassemble any further from this point onwards, please help to open it up in order to replace or lube the parts which are stuck.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried tapping on one end of the axle to push the bearings out?

Answer (score 4):

To remove the freehub the axle has to come out. Before you start source two new bearings as it is likely they will need to be replaced after you remove the axle. You can try to "gently" tap on the axle with a soft faced hammer (hard plastic or brass). In a pinch you can also place a block of wood on the axle and hit the wood with a steel faced hammer. One side may slide out easier than the other so try both sides. Once the axle is out of the way insert a large (most are 10mm but some are 11)  allen wrench into the nondrive side and unscrew the retainer. An 11mm allen can be hard to find, I use a 7/16" which is easier to find and cheaper.